# Subtracting seconds from one row and setting result to a different row in R

Tags: r, time

I have a dataframe where the first column is Time. My current output looks like:

0:0:0 
0:0:0 
5:43:42 pm 
5:43:52 pm

I'm trying to make a portion of my code search for any rows that have the 0:0:0 value in them and subtract 10 seconds from the closest row with a value in it. The desired outcome would look like:

5:43:22 pm
5:43:32 pm
5:43:42 pm
5:43:52 pm

I've written this portion of the code to do this for me. It runs with no errors, but doesn't actually change any values.

```
  entries<-length(data$Time)
  for(j in entries:1)
    if(data[j,1]=="0:0:0"){
      for(k in j-1:1)
        if(data[k,1]!="0:0:0"){
          data[k,1] <- as.POSIXct(data[k,1], format = "%H:%M:%S")
          value <- format(data[k,1] + seconds(10))
          data[j,1] <- value
          break
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions to go about creating this?

Comment: Could you post the data you are using, what the output is, and what you are looking to achieve?

Comment: What happens when a 0:0:0 time has equidistant values on either side?  Can non-zero values only succeed, and not precede, a zero value?

Comment: I updated the question to clarify my current output and desired output, please let me know if it's still not clear, it's a hard question for me to verbalize.

I could have non-zero values before and after the zero values. I'm assuming I would create an additional if or for loop statement to correct those ones, but if I'm mistaken please feel free to let me know. I'm very new to data analysis and R.

Comment: "It runs with no errors"? Nope, it doesn't run at all, could you check and edit that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the last value in your data would not be `'0:0:0'` you can do the following :

Replace `Time` with `NA` where the value is `0:0:0` and turn them to  `POSIXct` class.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Time = na_if(Time, '0:0:0'), 
         Time1 = as.POSIXct(Time, format = '%T')) -> df1
```

Replace `NA` value by subtracting 10 second from the next value.

```
for(i in nrow(df1):1) {
  if(is.na(df1$Time1[i])) {
    df1$Time1[i] <- df1$Time1[i + 1] - 10
  }
}
```

Change `POSIXct` in the desired `format` (H:M:S) that we need.

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(Time = format(Time1, '%T'), 
         Time1 = NULL) -> result

result

#      Time
#1 05:43:22
#2 05:43:32
#3 05:43:42
#4 05:43:52
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Time = c("0:0:0", "0:0:0", "5:43:42", "5:43:52"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` approach, assuming you mean by "closest row with a value" the nearest following row that is not "0:0:0":

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(Time=c("0:0:0", "0:0:0", "5:43:42 pm", "5:43:52 pm", 
                        "0:0:0", "6:43:52 pm"), c2=LETTERS[1:6])
DT[Time=="0:0:0", Time := NA]
DT[, Time := as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%I:%M:%S %p")]
i <- which(is.na(DT$Time))
DT[, idx:=cumsum(!is.na(Time))]
DT[, idx:=rev(seq(.N)), by=idx]
DT[, Time := nafill(Time, type="nocb")]
DT[i, Time:=Time - (10*idx)][, idx:=NULL]
DT[, Time := format(Time, '%I:%M:%S %p')][]
#>           Time c2
#> 1: 05:43:22 PM  A
#> 2: 05:43:32 PM  B
#> 3: 05:43:42 PM  C
#> 4: 05:43:52 PM  D
#> 5: 06:43:42 PM  E
#> 6: 06:43:52 PM  F
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>